# 特定のファイルだけ「折り返さない」で表示させたい

Tags: emeditor

ふだん、ファイルは指定文字数で折り返しにして表示するように設定しています。
ある特定のファイル（それは「ファイル」下のお気に入りの一覧に常に表示させています）を開いたときだけ、最初から「折り返さない」で表示することはできますか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmEditor はベータ版を含めて最新版 (v21.4.902 以上) に更新してください。EmEditor Professional の場合には、[ツール] メニューの [カスタマイズ] を選択し、[編集] ページの [.editorconfig を使用する] が設定されていることを確認してください。EmEditor Free の場合には、この設定はありませんが、常に有効の状態になってます。

そして特定のファイルが存在するフォルダに `.editorconfig` という名前のファイルを作成し、その中身を、次のようにして保存ください。たとえば、特定のファイル名が `a.txt`, `b,txt`, `c.txt` だとすると、以下のようになります。

```
root = true

[{a,b,c}.txt]
max_line_length = off
```

以上で、通常は折り返しの設定であっても、特定のファイルを開いた時だけ、折り返さない設定になります。`.editorconfig` の書き方について、詳しくは、[EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) を、`max_line_length` プロパティについては、[EditorConfig Properties](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties) を参照してください。

Comment: 早速にありがとうございます。
「a.txt」のファイル名が「１.txt」など2バイト文字だとうまくいかないようです。
こちらの都合ですみませんが、特定のファイル名を2バイト文字にせざるをえません。

Comment: `.editorconfig` は、`UTF-8` (BOM無し) で保存する必要があります。`Shift-JIS` などで保存すると正しく動作しないので、ご確認ください。